# sockets,getting empty response from external domain

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have this code, simple socket C example code, it works fine for an simple servidor that I wrote and run on local computer,but if I try for example, get html from google web page, it delay significantly the time of reply and returns empty buffer.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <errno.h>


void bye(char * mmo);

void bye(char * mm) {
    printf("%s\n", mm);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void) {

    int tcpSocket, port;
    char buffer[256],err[256], *servername,* mm;

    struct hostent *server;
   struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    servername = "google.com";
    tcpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    port = 80;

    server = gethostbyname(servername);
    mm = "baa";

    if(tcpSocket < 0) {
        sprintf(err, "Can't to initialize TCP socket communication(%s).",   strerror(errno));
        bye(err);
    }   

    if(NULL == server) {
        bye("Server not found");
    }

     memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
              server->h_addr, 
           server->h_length);
   serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(connect(tcpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        sprintf(err, "failed internet connection. %s", strerror(errno));
        bye(err);
    }
    if(write(tcpSocket, mm, strlen(mm)) < 0) {
        sprintf(err, "Can't send.(%s)\n", strerror(errno));
        bye(err);
    } 

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    while(read(tcpSocket, buffer, 255) < 0) {
            printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    close(tcpSocket);
    printf("done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Don't you think Google returns you an empty buffer because you sent them a nonsense HTTP request?

Comment: No.It return 40* bad request in anyway.

Comment: What John Zwinck just said.  You're sending up 3 garbage bytes to a web server and are expecting to get something valid back.  Just type "telnet google.com 80" at the command prompt followed by typing "baa" after the connection is made.  Then wait a couple of minutes.  Google will close their end of the socket (as would almost any web server). Your read call will return 0 (and then subsequently -1 on the next loop).

Comment: Note if you telnet to google.com:80 and type "baa" followed by pressing enter you will get a 400 BAD request.  But that's not what your code sends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring the code that reads the result:

```
while(read(tcpSocket, buffer, 255) < 0) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Such code only prints out the buffer´s content in case read() returned a vlaue less then 0, which read does in case of an error.

You might like to modify your code like so:

```
{
  size_t sizeReadTotal = 0;
  size_t sizeToRead = 255;
  ssize_t ssizeRead = 0;
  while (sizeToRead && (ssizeRead = read(tcpSocket, buffer + sizeReadTotal, sizeToRead))) {
    if (0 > sizeRead) {
      if (EAGAIN == errno || EWOULDBLOCK == errno)
        continue;
      else
        break;
    }

    sizeToRead -= ssizeRead;
    sizeReadTotal += ssizeRead;
  }

  if (0 > ssizeRead)
    printf("read() failed after having read %dbytes: %s\n", sizeReadTotal, strerror(errno));

  printf("Data read: '%s'\n", buffer);
}
```

Further more you should also send the '\n' to the server also (as selbie mentioned), so change:

```
mm = "baa";
```

into

```
mm = "baa\n";
```